Is there any property that I can add to the MongoDB validation schema to add additional information without impacting the validation of new documents?
Is there any way I can insert a property into this validator for inserting documents into MongoDB that will not impact validation but that I can retrieve via query?
To give some context: I use the validator to create a form dynamically, and I need some extra information to create the form according to my needs.
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    required: [
      'active',
      'productive',
      'translation',
      'code'
    ],
    properties: {
      code: {
        bsonType: 'string',
        minLength: 0,
        maxLength: 50,
      },
      active: {
        bsonType: 'bool'
      },
      productive: {
        bsonType: 'bool'
      },
      translation: {
        bsonType: 'object',
        properties: {
          'pt-BR': {
            bsonType: 'object',
            required: [
              'description'
            ],
            properties: {
              description: {
                bsonType: 'string',
                minLength: 0,
                maxLength: 50
              }
            }
          },
          'en-US': {
            bsonType: 'object',
            required: [
              'description'
            ],
            properties: {
              description: {
                bsonType: 'string',
                minLength: 0,
                maxLength: 50
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      audit: {
        bsonType: 'object',
        required: [
          'user'
        ],
        properties: {
          user: {
            bsonType: 'string'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


MongoDB is based on JSON Schema draft-04. By the Specification, unknown keywords should be ignored during validation.
A common pattern for unknown or custom keywords is to prefix x-
{
  $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: 'object',
    x-mycustomKeyword: {
      bsonType: 'string'
    }
  }
}

